# Как увеличить вкладку notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

Ребят есть код (пример)

```
 from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import ttk  
  
  
tk = Tk()  
tk.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение PythonRu")  
tk.geometry('900x900')  
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(tk)    
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)  
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)  
tab_control.add(tab1, text='Первая')  
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Вторая')  
lbl1 = Label(tab1, text='Вкладка 1')  
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
lbl2 = Label(tab2, text='Вкладка 2')  
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=0)  
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')  
tk.mainloop()
```

Если его запустить сверху будет 2 кнопочки которые переключают окна, они очень маленькие. Возможно ли их переместить и увеличить ?
Если да то как ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого используются стили:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



root = Tk()
root.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение PythonRu")
root.geometry('900x900')

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TNotebook.Tab', width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), font='helvetica 20', padding=20)

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='Первая')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Вторая')
lbl1 = Label(tab1, text='Вкладка 1')
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
lbl2 = Label(tab2, text='Вкладка 2')
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=0)
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```

Максимальная ширина растянет вкладки по максимому, размером шрифта и отступами можно регулировать высоту вкладок. Если хотите копнуть поглубже, то можно поменять весь макет.
tk заменил на root, так как он используется часто как алиас при импорте модуля tkinter.

Comment: А можно перенести его в низ ?

Comment: Пробуйте, все в ваших руках.